# What would you call a "fidget spinner" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Having recently been asked by my daughter to purchase a fidget spinner for her, I began wondering what the toy would be called in Esperanto.

[image: fidget spinner]

Comment: I think [*ŝpini*](http://vortaro.net/#%C5%9Dpini) is only ‘to spin’ in the sense of weaving fabric or secreting it (like a spider).

Answer (score 12):

There is a word *[turbo](https://eo.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo)* which means a spinning top. Maybe you could call it a *manturbo* which I think sounds quite cool.

Comment: Manturbado estas nova ŝatokupo de junaj knaboj lastatempe

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a proper translation for "fidget" manrotaciilo would be closer to a literal translation.
Rotacianta ludilo would work as a more abstract translation.